# Implementing checkbox with custom Adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I am trying to get my checkbox in custom adapter works. However, there is still a small part that I'm not getting thus, my program keep getting force closed each type I try to test it out.

This is a file manager which list out all image files in the sdcard.

```
public class FileBrowserMusic extends ListActivity {

    private File currentDir;
    private FileArrayAdapter adapter;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.music_main);

        currentDir = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
        List<Option>flss = new ArrayList<Option>();
        listFiles (currentDir, flss);
        Collections.sort (flss);
        ArrayAdapter<Option> adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(this, flss);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
    }

    // Recursively search for all image files.
    private void listFiles (File f, List<Option> flss) {
        if(f.isDirectory()){
            File[] files = f.listFiles();

            try {
                for (File ff : files){
                    if(!ff.isDirectory()) {
                        if(ff.getName().endsWith(".jpg")) {
                            Log.d(" FILES",ff.getName());
                            flss.add(new Option (ff.getName(),"Files Size: "+ff.length(),ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        listFiles(ff, flss);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                //e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

}
```

This is my adapter class.

```
public class FileArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Option> {

    private Context c;
    private int id;
    private List<Option>items;
    private Activity context;

    public FileArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Option> objects) {
        super(context, R.layout.music_view, objects);

        this.context = context;
        items = objects;
    }

    public Option getItem (int i) {
        return items.get (i);
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name, size;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // View v = convertView;
    final Option o = items.get(position);
    /*if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.music_view, null);*/
    View v = null;
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.music_view, null);

        //TextView t1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.backDot);
        //TextView t2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.backPDir);
        viewHolder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.size = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.size);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Option element = (Option) viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
                element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                Log.v("Checked : ", ""+ element.getName());
            }

        });

        v.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(items.get(position));

    } else {
        v = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) v.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(items.get(position));
    }

    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    holder.name.setText(o.getName());
    holder.size.setText(o.getPath());
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(o.isSelected());

    return v;
}

}
```

My option class.

```
public class Option implements Comparable<Option>{

    private String name;
    private String data;
    private String path;
    boolean selected = false;

    public Option (String n, String d, String p) {
        name = n;
        data = d;
        path = p;       
    }

    public Option (String n, String d, String p, boolean s) {
        name = n;
        data = d;
        path = p;       
        selected = s;       
    }

    public void setName (String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    public void setData (String d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public void setPath (String p) {
        path = p;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getPath() {
        return path;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected (boolean s) {
        this.selected = s;
    }

    public int compareTo(Option o) {
        if (this.name != null) {
            return this.name.toLowerCase().compareTo(o.getName().toLowerCase());
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }

}
```

And lastly, my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:text="@+id/name" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

    <TextView android:text="@+id/size"
        android:layout_below="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/sub"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:textSize="15sp"></TextView>

    <CheckBox android:id="@+id/check" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        ></CheckBox>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Where did I went wrong? Initially, my code was for only listing out image files in listview. After which, I tried to implement checkbox but unable to.

Appreciate it.

The code are quite messy as of now, due to all the testing and stuff.

T1 and T2 are my codes previously when I doing the file manager. Can ignore it, shouldn't mess with my current code I guess. I will remove it and test.

This is my log.

```
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at sg.joogle.safeit.FileArrayAdapter.getView(FileArrayAdapter.java:98)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-29 18:37:56.086: E/AndroidRuntime(4299):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat after the force close?

Comment: First of all post your logcat trace...and secondly t1,t2 are null as there are no views associated with them in the above layout

Comment: Hi @Pragnani I have posted the log cat. And edited the post

Comment: @user1778855 What is line no 98 in FileArrayAdapter

Comment: @Pragnani holder.name.setText(o.getName()); In my post, I did put a comment on the line that the error occurs

Comment: Set your ViewHolder viewholder=null in getview and create holder when view is null i.e   final ViewHolder viewHolder =null and in   if (convertView == null) { instantiate it like this viewholder=new ViewHolder();

Comment: Please check this two links: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html & http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2012/04/milti-selection-listview-android-with.html

Comment: I think I somehow got it working. I tried to redo it, with all classes in one file and followed the tutorial. Thanks for all the help. Now I need to know which checkbox was selected and such.

Answer (score 0):

you check for o !- null, but then outside of that if block you assign the setText
with o.getName.    Is it possible that o was really null at that point?

Comment: I have made changes to the getView function, and remove those unnecessary codes. Right now, I can open without having force close, but it does not show me anything. Is there anywhere I did wrongly?